# Spark Shell - passing variable into closure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am running the Spark shell (1.2.1) in local mode and I have a simple `RDD[(String,String,Double)]` with about 10,000 objects in it.
I get a `StackOverFlowError` each time I try to run the following code (the code itself is just representative of other logic where I need to pass in a variable). I tried broadcasting the variable too, but no luck .. missing something basic here -

```
val a=10
rdd.map(r => if (a==10) 1 else 0)
```

This throws

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:318)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1133)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)

...

...
```

Appreciate the help!

Edit - Tried with 1.4.1 and it didnt work. More goofiness -

This works -

```
val lst = Range(0,10000).map(i=>("10","10",i:Double)).toList
sc.makeRDD(lst).map(i=> if(a==10) 1 else 0)
```

But this doesn't and throws the StackoverflowError -

```
val lst = MutableList[(String,String,Double)]()
Range(0,10000).foreach(i=>lst+=(("10","10",i:Double)))
sc.makeRDD(l).map(i=> if(a==10) 1 else 0)
```

Comment: What is the type of the actual variable being passed in? This is a serialization issue, where it is thrashing on the serialization effort.

Comment: Just an int the code above. In the real use case I will probably be passing in a Map[(String,String), Int]. I got the same overflow error with the Map, so tried creating a broadcast variable out of it and then finally just tried with an int above and still get the error.

Comment: Works fine here almost as-is in Spark Shell 1.4.1.  I used `val rdd = ...`

Comment: @Paul - Were you using standalone mode? I am going to try 1.4.1 too

Comment: Tried 1.4.1 and didn't work. Also tried a couple of other things that I posted above ..

Comment: A parameterized class that is serializable could be useful here.  See the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32217660/103081)